# EF6 Linq query not returning results for some parameter values but SQL statement does

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

Problem summary:
Web app that displays records based on selections on the screen.  Those records get returned as a result of an EF query which takes two parameters.  For one particular selection, there are no results returned, yet I can get the data if I write a sql statement myself.  However, the EF query returns results as expected for other input values.

Strange scenario comparing EF query and SQL query.  Some of my data I was running some checks on, looking for orphaned records and found what appear to be some.  Using the application that hits the same database, there were no records returned via the EF query that gets run (which was what I expected).  Yet, after running a few test queries on my own, was when I discovered some data that SHOULD seem to be getting returned to the application.  I captured that EF query with profiler, and wrote what I thought was an equivalent statement in SQL to compare with.

Ive updated my model, rebuilt the project etc, but at the heart of it, the problem seems to be data-dependent, because the EF query returns results

The issue is that for the selected data parameters (inputs), I get results in a SQL query that I write myself, but get nothing from the one that EF generates - which results in a dynamic sql statement executed with sp_executesql.

EF SQL  (**This returns empty**)

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project1].[GoalId] AS [GoalId], 
    [Project1].[Year] AS [Year], 
    [Project1].[Name2] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[BusinessLineId] AS [BusinessLineId], 
    [Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
    [Project1].[CommodityId] AS [CommodityId], 
    [Project1].[DivisionId] AS [DivisionId], 
    [Project1].[Name3] AS [Name2], 
    [Project1].[MetricTypeId] AS [MetricTypeId], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name3], 
    [Project1].[TargetAvg] AS [TargetAvg], 
    [Project1].[TargetTotal] AS [TargetTotal], 
    [Project1].[Projected] AS [Projected]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[GoalId] AS [GoalId], 
        [Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
        [Extent1].[TargetTotal] AS [TargetTotal], 
        [Extent1].[TargetAvg] AS [TargetAvg], 
        [Extent1].[Projected] AS [Projected], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent4].[CommodityId] AS [CommodityId], 
        [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name1], 
        [Extent5].[BusinessLineId] AS [BusinessLineId], 
        [Extent5].[Name] AS [Name2], 
        [Extent7].[MetricTypeId] AS [MetricTypeId], 
        [Extent7].[Name] AS [Name3], 
        [Extent9].[DivisionId] AS [DivisionId]
        FROM         [dbo].[Goal] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GoalSpread] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[GoalSpreadKey] = [Extent2].[GoalSpreadId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessLineCommodity] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[BusinessLineCommodityKey] = [Extent3].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Commodity] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[CommodityKey] = [Extent4].[CommodityId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessLine] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[BusinessLineKey] = [Extent5].[BusinessLineId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[BusinessLineMetricType] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[BusinessLineId] = [Extent6].[BusinessLineKey]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MetricType] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[MetricTypeKey] = [Extent7].[MetricTypeId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DivisionBusinessLine] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent5].[BusinessLineId] = [Extent8].[BusinessLineKey]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Division] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[DivisionKey] = [Extent9].[DivisionId]
        WHERE (([Extent9].[Code] = @p__linq__0) ) AND ([Extent1].[Year] = @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[BusinessLineId] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000),@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0='De664f9ec-6f7a-4434-bdfc-b7832a3c9111',@p__linq__1=2015
```

My SQL statement to test: (**this returns results**)

```
    --test
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Goal g
JOIN dbo.GoalSpread gs  ON g.GoalSpreadKey = gs.GoalSpreadId
JOIN dbo.BusinessLineCommodity blc ON g.BusinessLineCommodityKey = blc.Id
JOIN dbo.Commodity c ON blc.CommodityKey = c.CommodityId
JOIN dbo.BusinessLine bl ON blc.BusinessLineKey = bl.BusinessLineId
JOIN dbo.BusinessLineMetricType blm ON bl.BusinessLineId = blm.BusinessLineKey
JOIN dbo.MetricType mt ON blm.MetricTypeKey = mt.MetricTypeId
JOIN dbo.DivisionBusinessLine dbl ON bl.BusinessLineId = dbl.BusinessLineKey
JOIN dbo.Division d ON g.DivisionKey = d.DivisionId
WHERE   d.Code = 'De664f9ec-6f7a-4434-bdfc-b7832a3c9111' AND g.Year = 2015
```

Comment: Simple question: Does your Connection String has `|DataDirectory|`? There is posibility you connect to different DBs

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I checked as thats caught me more than once :=)  My connection string is referencing the correct DB/server

Comment: You execute the EF SQL shown on top, manually in SSMS, and it returns a different result set than the SQL statement below it, also ran in SSMS in the same DB?

Comment: Check here  in EF you have `N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)` are you sure this shouldn't be GUID/UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Comment: Check if changing type in your model type to `uniqueidentifier` helps.

Comment: @ srutzky  - no, the EF SQL returns 0 results in SSMS, the same as when run through the application.  My own SQL statement, which is shown above and uses the same join conditions, returns results however.

Comment: @ lad2025 - Ive been using it this way for months and it works for some values, just not this particular input value and a few others.  So, it really seems to be data dependent.  However, what Im more puzzled about is why I can get results writing my own statement where as the EF query returns empty for the same input value.

Comment: `SELECT CAST('De664f9ec-6f7a-4434-bdfc-b7832a3c9111' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.`

Comment: It looks like missing one character.

Comment: Has  `Division.Code`  datatype UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Comment: I know what your thinking, but Division.Code is set to varchar(100) in the schema.  The data in the input parameter is correct, its how EF sees it and uses it that has an issue, or at least thats my take on it.  Somewhere there is a join condition that is failing most likely, causing the whole query to return empty.  However, that should happen on my version as well it seems.

Comment: So you are 100% the problem is not of implicit conversion?

Comment: Yes, since every one of those values will NOT convert directly to a guid.  Its simply a varchar.

Comment: Try this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM joins` without where condition. Run using your code and EF sp_execute sql and check if there are the same or try with only year.

Comment: In my opinion they are just different queries.

Comment: @lad2025 - thanks, but it turns out that I get the same count in both cases.

Comment: Ok but without actual data and data structure I can't help more. Different join condition can cause subtle errors.

Comment: What happens if you just run the inner `SELECT [Extent1]...` in the EF query in SSMS, and don't include the outer part (which includes the `ORDER BY`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at both queries and find how it joins.
Best ways is to take EF query use Notepad REPLACE ALL [Extent1] with 'g', do for all aliases in EF and use diff tools to compare and spot differences.

One example below:

SSMS:

```
FROM dbo.Goal g
(...)
JOIN dbo.Division d ON g.DivisionKey = d.DivisionId
```

EF:

```
FROM [dbo].[Goal] AS [Extent1]
(...)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Division] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[DivisionKey] = [Extent9].[DivisionId]
```

EF query replaced to your format, execute this in SSMS, should return nothing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Goal g
JOIN dbo.GoalSpread gs  ON g.GoalSpreadKey = gs.GoalSpreadId
JOIN dbo.BusinessLineCommodity blc ON g.BusinessLineCommodityKey = blc.Id
JOIN dbo.Commodity c ON blc.CommodityKey = c.CommodityId
JOIN dbo.BusinessLine bl ON blc.BusinessLineKey = bl.BusinessLineId
JOIN dbo.BusinessLineMetricType blm ON bl.BusinessLineId = blm.BusinessLineKey
JOIN dbo.MetricType mt ON blm.MetricTypeKey = mt.MetricTypeId
JOIN dbo.DivisionBusinessLine dbl ON bl.BusinessLineId = dbl.BusinessLineKey
/*JOIN dbo.Division d ON g.DivisionKey = d.DivisionId*/
JOIN dbo.Division d ON dbl.DivisionKey = d.DivisionId
WHERE   d.Code = 'De664f9ec-6f7a-4434-bdfc-b7832a3c9111' AND g.Year = 2015
```

Comment: thanks for all the help.  For now, im going to fire up linqpad and hit this from there.

Comment: @bitshift See my edited answer. I prepare EF query in your format. They have one line different.

Comment: I found it!  Same as your answer.  It was the DivisionBusinessLine and Division...After starting from scratch with the EF query in Linqpad, I started with the base table and one-by-one added the joins back.  Thats when I realized where the problem was.  The EF query was correct, but my SQL query I was trying to compare to was off as it didnt include one of the equivalent joins. <br/>  This isn't the first time Linqpad has saved me from going bonkers.  Thanks again for all the help.  I marked your post as the answer

Comment: @bitshift This kind of bugs are nightmares when you are in front of computer for many hours and try to figure out where is the difference ;) Especially when answer should be delivered quickly.